# When invoking the super method, what is i referring to?

Tags: java, superclass, super

I'm trying to learn the concept of `super`. Could someone please tell me what the `i` in `super(i)` is referring to?

Is it the private `int` variable `i` in the `NaturalNumber` class? Is it the parameter in the `NaturalNumber?` Is it referring to something else? I'm very confused by the syntax.

```
 class NaturalNumber {

    private int i;

    public NaturalNumber(int i) { this.i = i; }
    // ...
}

class EvenNumber extends NaturalNumber {

    public EvenNumber(int i) { super(i); }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: There is only one possibility, as there is only one `i` visible at the point that `super()` is invoked. The super class's instance variable is private and therefore invisible at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super(arguemnts)` is call to superclass constructor to which you pass `arguments`.
In case of `class EvenNumber extends NaturalNumber` it is mechanism which ensures NaturalNumber*ness* of your class.

What happens in this case is that you are passing to `super`class constructor same value you passed to `EvenNumber` class via `public EvenNumber(int i)`. So it will initialize `private int i` field (which you don't have direct access to from `EvenNumber` since it is private).

Maybe you will better see it if we rename variables a little:

```
class NaturalNumber {

    private int value;

    public NaturalNumber(int naturalValue) {
        this.value = naturalValue;
    }
    // ...
}

class EvenNumber extends NaturalNumber {

    public EvenNumber(int oddValue) {
        super(oddValue);
    }
    // ...
}
```

So when you create instance of `EvenNumber` via `new EvenNumber(2)` first thing which happens in `EvenNumber(int oddValue)` constructor is `super(2)` which will invoke `NaturalNumber(int naturalValue)` constructor and pass `2` to it, which finally will set `int value` to `2`.

Answer (score 3):

In your example it is the constructor parameter of EvenNumber. The call `super(i)` passes the constructor parameter to the superclass constructor (by value, because it's a primitive). The superclass constructor is then storing that value in a private field.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `super(i)`, it will call the superclass's constructor.
The `super` keyword refers to the superclass (parent class). In this case, the superclass of your EvenNumber is NaturalNumber because Even number **extends** NaturalNumber. So basically, by saying `super(i)` you are saying `NaturalNumber(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class NaturalNumber {

private int i;

public NaturalNumber(int x) { this.i = x; }
// ...
}

class EvenNumber extends NaturalNumber {

public EvenNumber(int y) { super(y); }
// ...
}
```

Consider the code above. This code does the exact same thing as your code. I changed variable names to make it clear. So, when you call super(y), what it does is call it's parent class's constructor, which is NaturalNumber(i), the value of y is passed on to this constructor, and inside this constructor you are setting the value of variable i equal to the value passed to constructor.

So when we call super(int), what it does is pass an integer value to the parent class's constructor.
Also, to set some variable of a parent class we can do `super.i=10` which will set the variable 'i' in the parent class to 10.

Answer (score 1):

The `i` in the `super` expression refers **exclusively** to the local variable `i` inside of your `NaturalNumber` class.  It does *not* expand its scope any further beyond that.

Answer (score -1):

The `super()` is supposed to be called with the same parameters as the Constructor of the super-class, as it does the exact same thing. For example :

```
    class Person {
        private name;

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Person() { /* Empty constructors initialize with default values,
                              i.e in this case name is initialized with null*/
        }
    }

    class Employee extends Person {
        private double salary;

        public Employee(double salary) {
            super("Michael");
            this.salary = salary;
            /* That means that the emplyee which is created is a person
               who's name is "Michael"*/
        }

        public Employee(double salary) {
            super();
            this.salary = salary;
            /* That means that the emplyee which is created is a person
               who's name is null as the empty constructor initialized it*/
        }
    }
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Doesn't answer what the `i` actually is, though; if it's bound to the child or the parent.

Comment: My answer is a basic explanation of what is, and does, `super()` in general, so @dzjustinli understands to what it refers in his problem. I was not as concerned about telling the solution as explaining the basic notions, as @dzjustinli is a beginer in java.

Comment: So you agree you haven't answered the question.

Comment: My answer would be different if it was addressed to an experienced java programmer, but in this case that's the best way for me to resolve the problem. And I hope this to be a valid opinion.